# Flutter - Visual Studio 2022 (Build Eexception)

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, cmake

Ao usar o Flutter com o **Visual Studio Community 2022** acontecia um erro ao tentar compilar para Windows Desktop. Percebi que no **Visual Studio Community 2019** ele compilava normalmente para o Windows Desktop. Uma solução que achei elegante e funcionou para mim sem precisar desinstalar o Visual Studio Community 2022 foi instalar o Visual Studio Community 2019 com as **Ferramentas para desenvolvimento com C++**(**Desktop development with C++**) e remover essa opção no Visual Studio Community 2022 ou seja removi as **Ferramentas para desenvolvimento com C++**(**Desktop development with C++**). Observação: Nas máquinas virtuais que uso com o Hyper-V com Windows 10 Professional ele compila normalmente usando a versão do Visual Studio Community 2022 sem precisar fazer nada em específico.

Tentei instalar a versão do compilador do Visual Studio 2019 no Visual Studio 2022, mas quando tentei instalar o C++ CMake Tools For Windows (Ferramenta do CMake do C++ para Windows) acabei forçando a instalação mais nova do compilador do C++ do Visual Studio 2022. Por isso resolvi instalar o Visual Studio 2019 separado.

**Mas a ideia era fazer funcionar somente utilizando o Visual Studio 2022** igual tenho feito nas máquinas Virtuais que uso no Hyper-V com Windows 10 Professional. De qualquer forma pelo menos consigo compilar e ainda manter o Visual Studio 2022 na máquina.

Comment: Na pergunta eu acabo também acrescentando uma possível solução no entanto o quê gostaria é saber se alguém sabe como fazer para funcionar somente utilizando o Visual Studio 2022 se possível.